# PHP replace {replace_me} with <?php include ?> in output buffer

Tags: php, include, buffer, output, str-replace

I have a file like this

```
**buffer.php**

ob_start();
<h1>Welcome</h1>

{replace_me_with_working_php_include}

<h2>I got a problem..</h2>
ob_end_flush();
```

Everything inside the buffer is dynamically made with data from the database.
And inserting php into the database is not an option.

The issue is, I got my output buffer and i want to replace '{replace}' with a working php include, which includes a file that also has some html/php.

**So my actual question is:** How do i replace a string with working php-code in a output-buffer?

I hope you can help, have used way to much time on this.

**Best regards - user2453885**

EDIT - 25/11/14

I know wordpress or joomla is using some similar functions, you can write {rate} in your post, and it replaces it with a rating system(some rate-plugin). This is the secret knowledge I desire.

Comment: Maybe you can learn something from them (WordPress): [The Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, unfornately this is not the technolegy behind it.

But until someone posts the anwser, I will try and locate the things i need in wordpress.

- Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty all for some lovely input.

I will try and anwser my own question as clear as I can.

**problem**: I first thought that I wanted to implement a php-function or include inside a buffer. This however is not what I wanted, and is not intended.

**Solution**: Callback function with my desired content. By using the function preg_replace_callback(), I could find the text I wanted to replace in my buffer and then replace it with whatever the callback(function) would return.

The callback then included the necessary files/.classes and used the functions with written content in it.

Tell me if you did not understand, or want to elaborate/tell more about my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace_callback and let the callback include the file you want to include and return the output. Or you could replace the placeholders with textual includes, save that as a file and include that file (sort of compile the thing)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it make sense, i'm reading stuff like that in the wordpress-code right now. I will check back later. Thanks for the input.
- user2453885

Answer (score 0):

For simple text you could do explode (though it's probably not the most efficient for large blocks of text):

```
function StringSwap($text ="", $rootdir ="", $begin = "{", $end = "}") {
            // Explode beginning
            $go =   explode($begin,$text);
            // Loop through the array
            if(is_array($go)) {
                    foreach($go as $value) {
                            // Split ends if available
                            $value  =   explode($end,$value);
                            // If there is an end, key 0 should be the replacement
                            if(count($value) > 1) {
                                    // Check if the file exists based on your root
                                    if(is_file($rootdir . $value[0])) {
                                            // If it is a real file, mark it and remove it
                                            $new[]['file']  =   $rootdir . $value[0];
                                            unset($value[0]);
                                        }
                                    // All others set as text
                                    $new[]['txt']   =   implode($value);
                                }
                            else
                                // If not an array, not a file, just assign as text
                                $new[]['txt']   =   $value;
                        }
                }
            // Loop through new array and handle each block as text or include
            foreach($new as $block) {
                    if(isset($block['txt'])) {
                            echo (is_array($block['txt']))? implode(" ",$block['txt']): $block['txt']." ";
                        }
                    elseif(isset($block['file'])) {
                            include_once($block['file']);
                        }
                }
        }

    // To use, drop your text in here as a string
    // You need to set a root directory so it can map properly
    StringSwap($text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contibution, it does not look like the thing I was looking for though. :)

Comment: Hmmm I thought you were looking to include your php file inside tags like so: `I want to run {/folder/file.php} in those tags` Maybe I read it wrong.

Comment: You got it right, it's just not the option i was looking for. However @Teyras and wordpress got it right. And I will return tomorrow and awser my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding something here, but something simple like this might work?

```
<?php

# Main page (retrieved from the database or wherever into a variable - output buffer example shown)
ob_start();

<h1>Welcome</h1>

{replace_me_with_working_php_include}

<h2>I got a problem..</h2>

$main = ob_get_clean();

# Replacement
ob_start();

include 'whatever.php';

$replacement = ob_get_clean();


echo str_replace('{replace_me_with_working_php_include}', $replacement, $main);
```

You can also use a return statement from within an include file if you wish to remove the output buffer from that task too.

Good luck!